# Deploying Google Sheets Extension

Tags: deployment, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, add-on, chrome-web-store

I've written a basic extension for Google Sheets and tried to go through the "Deploy as Sheets Web Add-on" wizard to deploy my extension for my own private use. However, I can't seem to find a way to search for the extension in Sheets.

I have deployed to the Chrome Web Store and can see the item (albeit with ADD TO CHROME greyed out, my first hint I've done something wrong) but when I try to search within Sheets "Add-ons" > "Get add-ons" performing a search for my add-on returns nothing.

I'm guessing I've deployed incorrectly but having gone over the documentation I still find myself at a loss:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish

Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong?
Also if any more information is required let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's set to **private**. If you want to see it in the search, you have to set it to **public**. You can read more of this in [Publishing an Add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish).

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. As stated, my extension is private and I brushed over reading the "Add-on review" paragraph due to the belief it would be irrelevant.
Extensions are only added to the Add-on store if they are public and after review.

Comment: You got it brah.